# Pyside with Python 3 Mac OS 10.8

Tags: python, pyside

I'm new at programing but I tried to find the answer for a week and could not solve my issue that seems to be easy.

I have a Macbook air with OS 10.8 and installed via Brew Python3 and Pyside using:

```
brew install pyside --with-python3
```

It install ok but when I try to import Pyside from terminal or from Pcharm it says:

> File "", line 1, in  ImportError: No module named
>   'pyside'

I know that it may seem simple, but I tried everything I found in the web but nothing works.

This time I reinstall a clean version of my OS to have a clean install and the result is the same.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.x/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947230/python-import-error-for-modules-installed-with-homebrew)

Comment: Uninstall `shiboken` and `pyside` first. Then reinstall `pyside --with-python3`.