# Installing PySide, QT on Mac OS X Problems

Tags: python, c++, macos, qt, pyside

I am a newbie at Mac so please excuse my ineptitude. What I'm trying to do here is pretty simple, I want to install Qt on Mac OS X 10.10.5.

To cut the story short, tried installing qt via brew first of all:-

```
brew install qt
```

or

```
brew install qt5
```

Here's the error I'm stuck at :-

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _map_fd
Referenced from: /usr/bin/install_name_tool
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _map_fd
Referenced from: /usr/bin/install_name_tool
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Tried installing it with MacPorts. No luck.

```
sudo port install qt4-mac
```

I tried re-installing the Xcode Command line tools as someone suggested in a thread at MacPorts. That didn't fix anything at all.

My original intention is to install PySide with Python3.4 on my mac.I'm trying to fix dependencies of PySide cmake then qmake.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329419/pyside-with-python-3-mac-os-10-8)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799514/installing-pyside-with-python3-on-os-x) - but none of them worked for me.

I installed python 3.4.4. And [installed pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082935/how-to-install-pip-for-python3-on-mac-os-x) & easy_install. I tried running this:-

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/easy_install PySide`

This of course asked me for dependencies. I downloaded & installed cmake. This wasn't coming up in command line so I looked after and found that command line must be installed using:-

```
sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" —install
```

With cmake and command line cmake installed , I tried installing PySide but of course it requires more dependencies. So I'm now trying to get Qt on my machine. But now I seem to have reached a place where I really don't know what to do. If someone already did it before, please help.