# Importing modules installed via Homebrew into Python

Tags: python, homebrew, graph-tool

Installed graph-tool via homebrew using
`$ brew install graph-tool`

Installation was successful. Now, when I try to import the module in the python shell, using `from graph_tool.all import *`

I receive a **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graph_tool'** error

Python version info- **Python 3.8.5**, installed via pyenv  at `/Users/aamodpant/.pyenv/shims/python`

**graph-tool** installed in **/usr/local/Cellar/graph-tool**

How do I import this into my python program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a very similar issue to the one in this post: [How to let python3 import graph-tool installed by Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521774/how-to-let-python3-import-graph-tool-installed-by-homebrew)

Have a look at the top answer provided by NatKost where they created a symbolic link between graph-tool and the Python packages:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/graph-tool/2.26_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graph_tool /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

You should be able adapt this for your graph-tool install and your venv.

Comment: This worked! Although now I am getting a similar error with error with numpy. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`.

numpy is also installed from brew. Do I add a similar "symbolic link" from numpy to graph-tool?

Comment: How did you install numpy? When using Python it's best to install packages using pip. So for example, when you have your venv active in the terminal, you would call 'pip install numpy' and this would install this package directly to your active virtual environment.

Comment: Hey, numpy was installed as a dependency for graph-tool automatically, therefore home-brew was used. I added 2 more symbolic links, and now it works. I am going to post an answer with all the commands I used. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this site [here](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python) and see whehter your problem is fixed. Alternatively, check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947230/python-import-error-for-modules-installed-with-homebrew)

I would recommend installing using `pip`.

Comment: `graph-tool` cannot be installed with `pip`, because `pip` is not a suitable package manager for projects with complex C++ builds with many dependencies. It is available via conda-forge, however.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Robert Young, for leading me to the right post [How to let python3 import graph-tool installed by Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521774/how-to-let-python3-import-graph-tool-installed-by-homebrew)

Because numpy and scipy are dependencies of graph-tool, they were installed automatically using home-brew when installing graph-tool.

After editing the command shown in the linked solution, I added a symbolic link between graph-tool and my python

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/graph-tool/2.33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graph_tool /Users/aamodpant/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

added similar links between numpy, scipy and python

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.19.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy /Users/aamodpant/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/scipy/1.5.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy /Users/aamodpant/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```